# How do I save a Document Library inside a sub folder?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, sharepoint-foundation, library

This may seem like a very simple question, but I want to organize the Site Content by putting in some folders for the Document Libraries.

Does anyone know how I can move document libraries within the site into sub-folders and/or how I can create document libraries inside folders.

Right now when I View-All-Site-Content all of the document libraries get displayed one after another, and I would really like to categorize them for ease of use.

Everytime I try to move the document library in SharePoint Designer it tells me that the action I am performing is forbidden for document libraries/lists.

Please help me if you can,
Thank You!!
MyName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. You are thinking of SharePoint as if it is a file system, which it is not. To organise content into "folders" you'd need to create subwebs and move libraries there.

But the wiser thing to do would be to correctly assign content types and metadata to your documents, then use search to find what you need. I know this is a very different way of thinking for most (new) users (who are used to a file system's tree structure), but in the end it'll safe you time, allow you to aggregate content by applying different filters (and still have only 1 wokring copy of a file) and all in all make your life much easier :-D